# Сохранить смещение объекта в html при трансформации

Tags: css, css3, transform

Использую CSS3-трансформации. Как сохранить положение квадрата после смещения?
Как в CSS3 создать таблицу стилей объекта до и после изменений?

```css
 .kvadrat4{ 
 width:100px; 
 height:100px; 
 background:#444;
 margin:30px;
 }
  
 .kvadrat4:hover{ 
 width:100px; 
 height:100px; 
 background:#444;
 margin:30px;
 -ms-transform: translate(15px,40px);
 -webkit-transform: translate(15px,40px);
 -o-transform: translate(15px,40px);
 -moz-transform: translate(15px,40px);
 transform: translate(15px,40px);
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="kvadrat4"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Вам нужно чтобы после наведения мыши на квадрат, ваш квадрат сместился и оставался таким даже после наведения?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего через JS\JQ.

Ну а если надо через CSS, то так:

```css
.kvadrat4 { 
  width:100px; 
  height:100px; 
  background:#444;
  margin:30px;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: kvadrat;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
  
.kvadrat4:hover {
  width:100px; 
  height:100px; 
  background:#444;
  margin:30px;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes kvadrat {
  to {
   -ms-transform: translate(15px,40px);
   -webkit-transform: translate(15px,40px);
   -o-transform: translate(15px,40px);
   -moz-transform: translate(15px,40px);
   transform: translate(15px,40px);
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="kvadrat4"></div>
```